FastAPI child process gets killed even with enough unused RAM and CPU left in the machine
I have a FastAPI server which fetches a lot of data from a database and does some data crunching ( ~20GB ) of data.
@app.post('/eval')
def exec_code(event: CodeModel, response: Response):
    try:
        init_duckdb()
        resp = eval_code(event.model_dump())
        # add empty inputs if not present
        if "inputs" not in resp:
            resp["inputs"] = {}

        if resp["success"]:
            return {"success": True, "body": resp["data"], "inputs": resp["inputs"]}
        else:
            response.status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            return {"success": False, "error": resp["error"], "inputs": resp["inputs"]} 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        return {"success": False, "error": {"errCode": "E106", "message": str(e)}}

These are the dependency versions being used
fastapi==0.115.6
fastapi-cli==0.0.5
uvicorn==0.34.0

The machine has 8 cores and 64GB of RAM.
If I run FastAPI server with no workers ( fastapi start src/api.py --port 3000 ) , the entire process completes successfully even after pulling all the data ( ~20-40GB of RAM utilisation )
But If I run the fastapi server with workers ( fastapi start src/api.py --port 3000 --workers 2 ), as soon as RAM utilisation hits ~4-5GB, the child process dies.
I'm just setting 2 workers to test. The behavior is consistent irrespective of the number of workers ( workers > 1 )

Here's what I've tried
I checked kernel logs using the following commands, but didn't get any output for it, so the kernel didn't kill the process because of an OOM issue.
journalctl -k | grep -i "oom"
journalctl | grep -E 'killed|SIGKILL'
sudo dmesg | grep -i "killed process"

I kept monitoring RAM and CPU usage using htop and the child process gets killed as soon as RAM usage hits ~4-5GB
We do not do any multi-processing inside the API call. It's all sequential.
There's no async usage in the code. It's all normal functions and the method decorated with the route also doesn't use async in the method definition.

did you try increasing log level
uvicorn src.api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 --workers 2 --log-level debug

Please have a look at this answer, as it would help you better understand how FastAPI works behind the scenes (since the last paragraphs of your question show some lack of understanding). It should also be noted that, as described in the linked answer, each worker has its own things, variables and memory. This means that global variables/objects, etc., won't be shared across the processes/workers. Hence, if you are consuming a large amount of memory in your code, each process will consume an equivalent amount of memory.

@Chris I understand that each worker process is isolated but when there's only one request being executed, I would want it to access all of the RAM, not just a portion of it. Even assuming each worker has limited access ( Total RAM / Total Workers ), my machine has 64 GB RAM and there are just two workers, so ideally the worker should not get killed before it reaches ~25GB of ram whereas I noticed the worker got killed as soon as it reached about 4GB
When I was testing, there was only one request fired and no congestion from other requests on other workers.

@gayanranasinghe I tried it, but no extra logs. I just get the one log 13|api     | INFO:     Child process [68530] died
